# Django form not inserting form values

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a from created which is generated by a model. I can save the form, but the form data is not inserted into the table. The insert occurs, but with blank data. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

models.py

```
class HelpDefinition(models.Model):
    org = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    help_type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    help_content = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
def index(request, org_id=None):
    help_def = HelpDefinition()

    if org_id:
        help_def = HelpDefinition.objects.get(org=org_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormHelp(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            help_def.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Saved!')
        else:
           messages.error(request, 'Ugh')
    else:
        form = FormHelp(request=request, initial=initial_data)

    return {
        'form': form,
    }
```

forms.py

```
class FormHelp(forms.Form):
    org = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=True)
    help_type = forms.ChoiceField(abel='Text', required=True)
    help_content = forms.CharField(label='Description', required=True, widget=forms.Textarea)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(FormHelp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due that you dont use `ModelForm`, you need to set your attributes one by one.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FormHelp(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        help_def.org = form.cleaned_data.get("org")
        help_def.help_type = form.cleaned_data.get("help_type")
        help_def.help_type = form.cleaned_data.get("help_content")
        help_def.save()
```

Comment: That returns the error unexpected keyword argument 'instance'. Seems that is due to the form not using ModelForm, but none of the other forms in this app I'm working with uses ModelForm.

Comment: well then you will need to assign your attributes one by one.